# How can I hide a link and reveal it onhover?

Tags: html, css

What I want is to use HTML and CSS (no JavaScript) to create a link that only appears when the mouse pointer hovers over it.  Attempts to use CSS' `display: none` and then switch to `display:block` for mouse hovers haven't worked for me. That's also true for switching `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible` for hovering.  In both cases, the link is invisible, but hovering over where it should be doesn't make it appear.

Thus, I've resorted to simply setting the foreground color to match the background color.  Crude but effective for now, but that means I have to make sure both settings are updated if the color scheme changes.  A simple example:

HTML:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum sum blah blah blah <a class="outOfSight" href="#theLink">the link</a></p>
<ul>
    <li>Just</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>nonsense</li>
    <li>to</li>
    <li>take</li>
    <li>up</li>
    <li>space</li>
</ul>
<br>
<a name="theLink">destination</a>
You have reached your destination!
```

CSS:

```
.outOfSight {
    color: white;
}
.outOfSight:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

It's also at http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4pB/4/.

Is this the only way? Or is there some subtlety to either the `display` or `visibility` property I don't know? Is there another way?

Comment: have you tried using the z-index in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using opacity?

```
.outOfSight {
    opacity: 0;
    color: black;
}
.outOfSight:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4pB/6/)

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware of the opacity property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover over something that is not there (`visibility` and `display` can both take the element out).  I would just set `opacity: 0` / `opacity: 1`.

Comment: The explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Without using something like jQuery, that's going to be your only answer.

Setting it to 'visibility:hidden' or 'display:none' take away the interactivity. 'display:none' just completely hides it like it's not there while 'visibility:hidden' keeps its 'mass' but hides it from sight but unfortunately takes away all of the interactivity.

Someone else suggested using opacity, which would work but it's not super browser friendly (if you're supporting the less fortunate that are still using older IEs).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about what `display` and `visibility` do.  Fortunately, I don't have to support older IE's for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr5jP/2/).

Surround the anchor in a `<span>`, and then apply the hidden to the child of the span as so:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum sum blah blah blah
    <span class="outOfSight"><a href="#theLink">the link</a></span>
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Just</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>nonsense</li>
</ul>
<br>
<a name="theLink">destination</a>
You have reached your destination!
```

Then your CSS would be:

```
.outOfSight { display: inline-block; }
.outOfSight a {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.outOfSight:hover a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I've think that layering elements like this is no better than putting tables inside tables.

Comment: No problem.  I can understand not wanting to add tags without a semantic purpose, but it is definitely not as bad as stacked Tables!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you.

**CSS**

```
.outOfSight {
    display:inline-block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.outOfSight:hover {
    text-indent:0;
}
```

More about text-indent property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although "indenting" off the screen seems like a worse kludge to me than making the foreground and background colors match.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Out {
display:none;
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}
.Out:hover {
display:inline:
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Neither of those are valid classes, and are being applied to html elements called `Out`

Comment: Mistaken, written in my iphone